# How do I use vector values as variables in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataframe called repay and I have created a vector for the variables names of the variables I am interested in called variables.

```
variables<-names(repay)[22:36]
```

I want to write a for loop that does some univariate analysis on each of the variables in variables. For example:

```
for (i in 1:length(variables))
{
model<-glm(Successful~ variables[i]
,data=repay
,family=binomial(link='logit'))
}
```

However it doesn't recognize `variables[i]` as a variable, giving the following error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Successful ~ variables[i], data
>   = repay,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'variables[i]')

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `assign` yielding in as many models as the variables. 
Let us consider

```
repay<-data.table(Successful=runif(10),a=sample(10),b=sample(10),c=runif(10))
variables<-names(repay)[2:4]
```

yielding:

```
>repay
    Successful  a  b         c
 1:  0.8457686  7  9 0.2930537
 2:  0.4050198  6  6 0.5948573
 3:  0.1994583  2  8 0.4198423
 4:  0.1471735  1  5 0.5906494
 5:  0.7765083  8 10 0.7933327
 6:  0.6503692  9  4 0.4262896
 7:  0.2449512  4  1 0.7311928
 8:  0.6754966  3  3 0.4723299
 9:  0.7792951 10  7 0.9101495
10:  0.6281890  5  2 0.9215107
```

Then you can perform the loop

`for (i in 1:length(variables)){
 assign(paste0("model",i),eval(parse(text=paste("glm(Successful~",variables[i],",data=repay,family=binomial(link='logit'))"))))
}`

resulting in 3 objects: `model1`,`model2` and `model3`.

```
 >model1
 Call:  glm(formula = Successful ~ a, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
 data = repay)
 Coefficients:
 (Intercept)            a  
   -0.36770      0.05501  
 Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  8 Residual
 Null Deviance:     5.752 
 Residual Deviance: 5.69    AIC: 17.66
```

Idem for `model2`, `model3` et.c.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `formula` function in R. It will allow correct interpretation of models as below:

```
for (i in 1:length(variables){
    myglm <- glm(formula(paste("Successful", "~", variables[i])),
                 data = repay, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

See [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941709/4001897) for more things you can do in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a language object from a string,

```
var = "cyl"
lm(as.formula(sprintf("mpg ~ %s", var)), data=mtcars)
# alternative (see also substitute)
lm(bquote(mpg~.(as.name(var))), data=mtcars)
```

Comment: Perhaps `reformulate` would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Small workaround that might help

```
 for (i in 22:36) 
{
  ivar <- repay[i] #choose variable for running the model
  repay2 <- data.frame(Successful= repay$Successful, ivar) #create new data frame with 2 variables only for running the model

  #run model for new data frame repay2
  model<-glm(Successful~ ivar
             ,data=repay2
             ,family=binomial(link='logit'))
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `i` run over `1:length(variables)` , hence `for (i in 1:length(variables)){...}`

Comment: Thanks @agerom! `repay` variable should be used in this place.

Comment: So now you don't need the `variables<-names(repay)[22:36]`, correct?

Comment: Indeed! Thanks again!